# pip fails to make a secure connection to pypi server

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, pip

Yesterday I tried to install some python packages with pip and it just won't work.

```
paquete@paquete-ultrabook:~$ pip install isort -v
Downloading/unpacking isort
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/isort/: connection error: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:344: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/isort/ when looking for download links for isort
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:344: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for isort
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/isort/: connection error: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:344: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/isort/ when looking for download links for isort
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement isort
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_paquete...
No distributions at all found for isort
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for isort

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpl86YQE
```

I've been arround searching for an answer in the internet without success. A lot of answers from 2012 suggest to downgrade, but the bug that was troublesome had been fixed since that.

```
paquete@paquete-ultrabook:~$ pip -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Some people had issues with their python interpreter, but it seems to connect fine to the server.

```
paquete@paquete-ultrabook:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("pypi.python.org")
>>> conn.request("GET","/simple/")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.status, res.reason
200 OK
```

As additional information, I did an elementaryos fresh install a few weeks ago. This happens to ALL packages. I have installed everything through apt, so this seems  Any ideas?

**Update**
Following the suggestion by @andersson I tried to install pip's latest version. Then this poped out

```
paquete@paquete-ultrabook:~$ sudo python3 Downloads/get-pip.py -v
The directory '/home/paquete/.cache/pip/log' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/paquete/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 253, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2734)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 762, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 255, in ssl_wrap_socket
    raise SSLError(e)
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2734)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 476, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 367, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/tmp/tmp8w985p0e/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2734)
```

It seems to be a generic problem.

Comment: To add more mystery, an old virtualenv pip works just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Promptly solved by:

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was slightly different. It looks like the https://pypi.python.org/simple/ certificate was renewed in June 2016, so if the date of your OS is prior to that date, you'll have problems validating the certificate, no matter if the proper CA certs are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also some issues with default (1.5.4) pip version. Can you successfully update pip to up-to-date (6.1.1) version or you have already tried and instalation failed with both pip versions?

Comment: I'm a bit glad that it's not just me. Following the steps at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html this came up when running get-pip.py.

/tmp/tmpRJjSJP/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
I will loke into this.